# Zend Framework Action Gets Called Twice

Tags: php, zend-framework

we are trying to build an application using the zend framework and have the following problem: "Some controller actions are called twice. This means that the actions gets called, finishes its execution and then gets called again".

We tracked this down by checking entries in a log file. For one request there where 2 entries in the log file.

Do you know anything that might be causing this problem? Is this related with the dispatch process of the Front Controller?

Regards,

Comment: Maybe your action is calling another function somewhere, that is calling the same action again?

Comment: I was facing this same problem and it took from me a good amount of time.I ended up having feeling that it was a very nasty joke.

Answer (score 5):

I found out that action got requested twice when Chrome Extension Webug (FirePHP extension for Google Chrome) was enabled.

Comment: I can not tell you how helpful this was. I had just about given up on this thread when I saw this. Thank you. What a mess to have this extension make a 2nd request. Whew. Anyway, much appreciate it. This was my issue as well.

Comment: Thanks mate, the double requests were driving me crazy but it was indeed the FirePHP (in my case, in Firefox) ---  correction, I don't have FirePHP in FF, it was FireBug itself that triggered the second call

Answer (score 2):

forward or action stack may be to reason

Answer (score 2):

try and use a debugger ( XDebug for example ) to see how your code is runned.
focus on the dispatcher, something must have happened and the request action is not set as dispatched so it gets runned again.

Answer (score 1):

It might be a bug.  Difficult to tell without more information.

Try logging a backtrace each time the action method is called.

```
<?php
trigger_error(var_export(debug_backtrace(), true));
trigger_error(var_export($_SERVER, true));
?>
```

This will give you tons of info in the error-log, so you'll want to export the result to a text-editor and munch through it there.  And/or possibly modify the code to print less info.

A couple of things to look for:

- Is the action-method called from different places?
- Is the $_SERVER['UNIQUE_ID'] (or REQUEST_TIME) different?

If the unique-id is different then you've done two requests to the server.  If not, try to figure it out from the backtrace.

Answer (score 1):

We were having a similar problem. Some actions were executed twice. After much debugging and googling, found out the problem was a bug in ZFdebug. Installed [this patch](http://code.google.com/p/zfdebug/issues/detail?id=37) and everything went back to normal. Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Chrome 17.0.x, Webug and Zend Framework 1.11.1 and still seeing this issue. I disabled Webug as suggested and the Action was only called once.

So, I think this is a bug in Webug.

Comment: I apologize for this error in Webug — in the current version it is fixed.